# Switching computer using a KVM reset my windows

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, kvm-switch

I have a [Starview KVM](http://www.startech.com/item/SV231DD2DUA-2-Port-Dual-DVI-USB-KVM-Switch-with-Audio-20-Hub.aspx). My first computer is a Desktop Windows Server 2008 and my second computer is a Windows XP 64 Professional Dell Laptop (with the display closed).

My problem is that when I'm switching away from my WinXP machine and back, all my windows lose their settings. It seems that Windows detects a resolution change and resets its display environment.

I wonder what's causing this problem. Is it the display drivers (I have the latest version)? Is it Windows? Or maybe it could be because Windows assigns the display environment to the integrated display of the laptop when I switch away?

Any suggestions?

---

To add a little clarification, I usually work with my application in "Window" mode. That is, not maximized. When I go back to my laptop, my windows are not positioned where they were. They go back to the upper left corner of my main window. They also lose the size that they had.

Comment: Please describe "all my windows loses their settings." Loss of keyboard can also upset windows, do you have your keyboard plugged into the KBM USB?

Comment: I meant "the windows" in my Windows. It's confusing, I agree :)